# find if a facebook user is single or married - facebook api

Tags: php, facebook

how can i do a search like this to search if an user is single or married?

```
$_friends = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$uid.' ) AND sex<>"'.$me['gender'].'"', ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do:

```
SELECT relationship_status FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

Or to get your friends relationship status too:

```
SELECT relationship_status FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

For the first one, you need the [`user_relationships`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) permission and for the later you need `friends_relationships`.

Result would be something like:

```
[
  {
    "relationship_status": "In a relationship"
  }
]
```

**A SIDE NOTE:**
You need to be careful comparing the `sex` and `relationship_status` fields against **one** value since the documentation is not clear how these fields are handled. More about this are described on this [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15693). (BTW please vote for the bug!)

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook got new API for getting user status... not sure the code u mention above still working though.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/